# TypeScript project failing to deploy to App Engine targeting Node 12 or 14, but works with Node 10

Tags: typescript, google-app-engine, package.json, app.yaml, google-appengine-node

I have a TypeScript project that has been deployed several times without any problems to Google App Engine, Standard environment, running Node 10. However, when I try to update the App Engine project to either Node 12 or 14 (by editing the `engines.node` value in `package.json` and the `runtime` value in `app.yaml`), the deploy fails, printing the following to the console:

```
> ####@1.0.1 prepare /workspace
> npm run gcp-build


> ####@1.0.1 gcp-build /workspace
> tsc -p .

sh: 1: tsc: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! ####@1.0.1 gcp-build: `tsc -p .`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ####@1.0.1 gcp-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

According to the following documentation, App Engine should be installing the modules listed in `devDependencies` in `package.json` prior to running the `gcp-build` script (which it has been doing, as expected, when deploying with the Node version set to 10).

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step

I can't find any documentation regarding how this App Engine deployment behavior has changed when targeting Node 12 or 14 rather than Node 10. Is there some configuration I am missing? Or does Google no longer install `devDependencies` prior to running the `gcp-build` script?

Here is the `devDependencies` section of my `package.json` (TypeScript is there):

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/nodejs-repo-tools": "^3.3.0",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.12",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
        "@types/pg": "^8.6.1",
        "@types/request": "^2.48.7",
        "tsc-watch": "^4.4.0",
        "tslint": "^6.1.3",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
    },
```

Comment: Are you able to run the app locally with the given Node 12 or 14 version?

Comment: @JavierA Yes, it works locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the exact same problem and just put typescript in dependencies, not devDependencies.

It worked after that, but cannot assure that it is due to this change (since I have no proof of that).

Comment: I tried this and it works, thank you. I had some other stuff in devDependencies as well and ended up having to move it all into dependencies to get the deploy to succeed.

Comment: I am glad it helped you :)